# Cannot find underlying module for 'Spring'

Tags: ios, swift

I can't seem to understand what is going on with my project and my cocoapods, Xcode cannot find the frameworks except Firebase which is why I am confused. I have tried to clean and build, empty Xcode's cache and reinstalling Xcode. Can anyone help with this. Thanks

Here's my pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Soar_iPad' do
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks! 
Pods for Soar_iPad
pod ‘Firebase’
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift2'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
#pod 'pop', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/pop.git'
end
```

And here is the error I keep getting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suGiL.png)

Comment: Are you opening **yourapp.xcworkspace**, instead of **yourapp.xcodeproj**?

Comment: Yes. I'm opening my .xcworkspace

Comment: Show the complete `podfile`. I'll check.

Comment: You can try removing pod and adding it again to project

Comment: @Dershowitz123 I updated my `podfile` in the original post

Comment: @Abhishek I tried that too...

Comment: Uncomment the line platform iOS. And try?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 No luck, same result